# All letters appear as Capital letters in Word 2007 even if CapsLock is off

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

In my Word 2007 all letters typing from or copying from some where else appears as capital letters. Things were fine till yesterday. I checked whether Caps Lock is on, but it is not. Is there any option in Word to capitalize all letters. How can I avoid this issue ?

Comment: There is. Although I do not remember the exact phrasing (I don't have Word with me), there's an option on the Font or Formatting menu that capitalizes all characters. It's just an effect though and you can disable it.

Comment: Sounds like your turn all capital letters on its turned on

Comment: Check [these settings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-the-capitalization-of-text-HA010210665.aspx)

Comment: @Ramhound Where is the Turn All Capital Letters option ?

Comment: @Torn Its a font option.